# Why are audio clicks/pops occurring when the position of a PannerNode is updated rapidly?

Tags: web-audio-api

I've been experimenting with the PannerNode for quite some time and in cases where I'm updating position of the panner repeatedly using either requestAnimationFrame() or setInterval(), I've noticed clicking/popping of audio.

Why is this happening and how can it be resolved?

I'd hoped that it would be fixed with the introduction of position as an AudioParam or I could circumvent the issue by using a ramp. I've tried setting the position with and without a ramp on Chrome Canary and the issue is still present.

You can hear it for yourself here: https://jsfiddle.net/txLke4fh/

Code snippet:

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
var panner = ctx.createPanner();
var temp = true;

osc.frequency.value = 220;
osc.connect(panner);

panner.panningModel = 'HRTF';
panner.setPosition(0, 0, 0);
panner.connect(ctx.destination);

osc.start(0);
osc.stop(ctx.currentTime + 10);

setInterval(function() {
  if (temp) {
    panner.setPosition(50, 0, 0);
    temp = false;
  } else {
    panner.setPosition(-50, 0, 0);
    temp = true;
  }
}, 100);
```

EDIT: It can be observed on Chrome Canary too, with and without a linear ramp.

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
var panner = ctx.createPanner();
var temp = true;

osc.frequency.value = 220;
osc.connect(panner);

panner.panningModel = 'HRTF';
panner.positionX.value = 0;
panner.connect(ctx.destination);

osc.start(0);
osc.stop(ctx.currentTime + 10);

setInterval(function() {
  if (temp) {
    panner.positionX.linearRampToValueAtTime(50, ctx.currentTime + 0.01);
    temp = false;
  } else {
    panner.positionX.linearRampToValueAtTime(-50, ctx.currentTime + 0.01);
    temp = true;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing an instantaneous move from one position to another. I certainly would expect a click, depending on how where you moved.

If you have Chrome canary, you should be able to use automation (but don't use `setPosition()` which doesn't do automation).  If you have an example of where it still clicks with automation, please post it; I'd like to see such an example.

Comment: When you mentioned automation, I assumed you meant using a ramp so please correct me if I misunderstood. 

Also, is there any way to avoid the clicks using setPosition()?

Comment: Yes, I meant to use a ramp using the new `positionX`, `positionY`, and `positionZ` AudioParams.  The best you can do with `setPosition` is don't move abruptly.  But there was an issue in Chrome where, if you did move smoothly, there were still glitches.  Chrome beta has the fix (and adds `positionX` for automation.

Comment: I added the automated position update code in the question. I used a ramp for changing the position and unfortunately, the clicks are still present.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Let me take a look.

Comment: Ok.  With help from a colleague, this is working correctly. Two issues here.  One is that your motion goes through the origin.  There's a discontinuity there so you get a click.  Set the initial X, Y, Z position away from the origin.  The other issue is that you are moving very fast (+50 to -50 in .01 sec).  If that were in meters, that would be faster than the speed of sound (about Mach 30.)

Comment: Alright, now it makes sense. Passing through the origin can be problematic (out of curiosity, is the discontinuity because there is no convolution being applied at the origin?). Also, shouldn't max speed be limited to less than the speed of sound in the spec, to avoid these clicks? Thanks for all the information.

Comment: I'd have to dig it out to be sure, but I think the discontinuity comes from the azimuth angle.  As you move through the origin, you suddenly change from, say, full left to full right.  This can cause a click.  Also, the spec doesn't have speed of sound any more; the example was just to show that you're moving unrealistically fast, assuming meters is your distance unit. The spec doesn't say what units are used.